# Few question about Microsoft Teams using bot

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

1. It is possible to force a bot to join (and listen) all teams, meetings, chats conversation in my tenant without being invited or beginning the conversation?
2. When a member was added to a team, my bot received a "conversationUpdate" message with the member that was added in the "memberAdded" field. I would also like to know if the bot has the ability to delete a member of a team used "memberRemoved" field?

3.Does the bot have the ability to delete a message / file from a channel / chat conversation?

4.Can the bot that is part of a meeting have the option of expelling a member from the meeting?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

1. No. Currently bot needs to be @mentioned in order to receive channel messages.
2. Member added/ removed are the events to notify of changes happening in Team. You cannot remove a member using these events. However, your bot can use [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0) to add/remove members provided you have valid [access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-overview?toc=./ref/toc.json&view=graph-rest-1.0).
3. Bot can not delete chat message but could [update existing message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conversations#updating-messages) sent by bot.  You can use Graph API to [read channel messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-get-message?view=graph-rest-beta).
4. No. The bot can access the list of participants, invite new participants, and mute them. Check [Calls and online meetings bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/calls-and-meetings/calls-meetings-bots-overview)

Comment: Would like to verify there is no way to add by code a BOT to channel/ Meeting?
What is the classic use case of a bot in a meeting? Do members of the meeting need to add the bot manually ?

Comment: Please check [Calls and online meetings bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/calls-and-meetings/calls-meetings-bots-overview) documentation for in detail explanation.